# Extending Jenkins Delivery Pipeline Plugin to display the history of a job

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I’ve been hacking on **[Jenkins Delivery Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Delivery+Pipeline+Plugin)** quite a bit now, and I’ve managed to create a table-like layout that is capable of displaying multiple different pipelines with A LOT of downstream jobs quite nicely. 
[sample img on twitter](https://twitter.com/schusterfredl/status/971008334772998144)

Now unfortunately I need to display the history of those pipelines, which in theory would not be a problem by just creating a own view for each pipeline, showing only the last N builds of ONE job, but this is not practical, as we’re talking about 20+ pipelines (having 3 to 10 downstream jobs each).

I know there is [Downstream Build View Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Downstream+buildview+plugin), but that does not allow me to track the history of a pipeline as well – so that is not really an option.

I need to extend Delivery Pipeline Plugin so that it *shows the last N runs of a pipeline* in the Job as well as in the Build (only one here, so this may still be done with Downstream Build View Plugin).

**Which extension points** do I need to implement / can the existing plugin (Delivery Pipeline Plugin) be easily extended to do so?

Comment: I've just managed to hook a summary.jelly on a specific run by implementing RunAction2 so far (configuration of the view is yet to coma) - but I'm still missing the build/job page.. any help is greatly appreciated!